# How to make a visualization (say a vertical bar graph ) between two field of a single index in kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have some set of data as

@day: 01-01-2016
@count: 20

@day: 02-01-2016
@count: 40

I want to see them as my @day on X-axis and @count on Y-axis

any help?

**Edit 1**
[image]

So I follow below suggestion, I am getting sum of all the values.
But I have:

```
@day 01-01-2016 @count 20
@day 08-01-2016 @count 50
@day 16-01-2016 @count 30
@day 24-01-2016 @count 10
@day 30-01-2016 @count 110
@day 08-02-2016 @count 50
@day 16-02-2016 @count 30
```

Sum is 300 ( as coming in graph)

and obviously, I need direct X-Y mapping.

any guesses where I am missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize > Vertical bar Chart > New Search > Select your index pattern.

To have the day on X-axis:
buckets: Select buckets type: X-Axis > Aggregation : Date histogram > Field: @day

To have the count on Y-axis:
metrics: Y-Axis: Aggregation > Sum > Field: @count

Of course, for it to work, you'll need to have the `@day` field as timestamp and the `@count` as integer

Result (with data provided by OP)

[image]

Comment: @baudspThanks for answer. yes You are right I am just learning all this.

Comment: Actually when I do the same as you mentioned, It takes the sum for all values

Comment: @AnandBajpai That's the problem, Kibana can't create scatter plot like excel. You might have better luck with the average.

Comment: ...please have a look on my Edit1

Comment: @AnandBajpai I think I misunderstood your problem. Kibana might also not be the right tool for this job. I'll see what I can do but no promises

Comment: okay got it ..But say I apply "term" agg on X-axis on my "day" so on Y-Axis it should so the "day-wise" Sum ...not the sum for whole ..Please correct me

Comment: @AnandBajpai Yes, but the problem is that I'm pretty sure that Kibana can't do direct X-Y mapping, so it will do aggregations

Comment: @AnandBajpai I have imported your data and I got an acceptable result (cf picture in my answer). I have no idea why you got this result

Comment: ...Sorry for late response...I got the issue .I was populating the data in the single document. That is why those results were coming...Thanks